# What is the length of the Hope XC internal spacer from freehub to bearing?

Tags: hub

I think I have a worn spacer as it has ragged edges.   Does anyone have the length of this spacer when new?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Hope's exploded view for the XC and Mono hub](http://www.hopetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/XCRearHubExploded.pdf)s, the spacer is 14mm.

[image]